# Regex match exact word

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have two inputs for registration part of my project:

1. password `<input type="password" ng-model="userData.password">`
2. confirm password  `<input type="password" ng-model="userData.confirmPassword">`

I am using ng-pattern to check if userData.confirmPassword is exactly same as userData.password using this:

```
<input ng-pattern="^userData.password$" ng-model="userData.confirmPassword">
```

The problem with the current code is that:

- If password is stackoverflow and confirm passwors is 123stackoverflow123, the regex will still match and will return true for my form.

What regex can I place to match only if the whole text is matching?

Comment: Why not just use a regular comparison instead of RegEx?

Comment: A regular comparison will not make the input invalid, in case the password are not matching :)

Comment: Use a custom validator.

Comment: I preffer to use pattern, is there any method available to check the whole input value?

Comment: why not use `ng-match`? `<input type="password" ng-model="userData.confirmPassword" ng-match="userData.password">`

Comment: This does not work :(

Comment: I don't really know Angular, but there's an example of what you're looking for in the API reference : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Answer (score 0):

The following change is recommended as per the [documentaion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern):

```
<input ng-pattern="{{userData.password}}" ng-model="userData.confirmPassword">
```